# No data to free space in phone

Tags: 8.1, storage

I've been using a Lumia 620 for the last 2 years. Now my phone is getting slower and slower. I have moved all my data to the SD card, but it is still showing only 500MB out of 8 GB. When try to remove data by accessing the folders it shows nothing in all the folders. I am confused now how I can make more space in my phone. See below screen shot from my "Storage Check" in Settings.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have over 4 GB worth of media and files on your phone. Try using Microsoft's [Files app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl) to view the files and move them to the SD card.

Comment: nothing in media and files. i dont know why it is showing like this

Comment: when I access Phone data using data card, all folders are empty.

Comment: Have you tried with the Storage Sense app? That can also move applicable apps to an SD card.